# IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class android.widget.SeekBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have received the following error after the activity launches, and upon clicking the confirm button on the profileactivity page:

```
IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class android.widget.SeekBar
```

I am essentially trying to record various information such on parse, to be able to retrieve it later.
Below is the logcat

```
08-13 14:56:24.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1306): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1365
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class android.widget.SeekBar
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:2152)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.parse.ParseUser.put(ParseUser.java:315)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation$1.onClick(ProfileCreation.java:136)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-13 15:49:13.758: E/AndroidRuntime(1365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

UPDATED CODE

public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

```
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
FrameLayout layout;
Button save;
protected EditText mName;
protected EditText mAge;
protected EditText mHeadline;
protected ImageView mprofilePicture;
RadioButton male, female;
String gender;
RadioButton lmale, lfemale;
String lgender;
protected SeekBar seekBarMinimum;
protected SeekBar seekBarMaximum;
protected SeekBar seekBarDistance;


protected Button mConfirm;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

    RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

    v.requestFocus();

    Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

    mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
    mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
    mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
    mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
    male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rimale);
    female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rifemale);
    lmale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlmale);
    lfemale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlfemale);
    seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
    seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
    seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);



    mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = mName.getText().toString();
            String age = mAge.getText().toString();
            String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();




            age = age.trim();
            name = name.trim();
            headline = headline.trim();

            if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                // create the new user!
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();





                if(male.isChecked())
                    gender = "Male";
                else
                    gender = "Female";

                if(lmale.isChecked())
                    lgender = "Male";
                else
                    lgender = "Female";


                currentUser.put("Name", name); 
                currentUser.put("Age", age); 
                currentUser.put("Headline", headline); 
                currentUser.put("Gender", gender);
                currentUser.put("Looking_Gender", lgender);
                currentUser.put("Minimum_Age", seekBarMinimum.getProgress());
                currentUser.put("Maximum_Age", seekBarMaximum.getProgress());
                currentUser.put("Maximum_Distance_Age", seekBarDistance.getProgress());




                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });



    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);
    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this

    Button mcancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    mcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ProfileCreation.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });




    SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
    final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMinAge);

    seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this

    SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
    final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMaxAge);

    seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        }

    }); // Add this




    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

} 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

    private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] data = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
        int bytes_read;
        while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
        }
        input_stream.close();
        return buffer.toByteArray();

    }
}
```

Layout code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dark_texture_blue" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="797dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:alpha="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRemove"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtname"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#330099"
        android:text="Upload from Facebook"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:text="Select photo from gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Preferred Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="Please type your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rimale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rifemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlmale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlfemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Search Distance "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Headline"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMinAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMaxAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbseekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer"
        android:textColor="#99CCFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvseekBarDistanceValue"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#151B54"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="A quick description of yourself"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please type your age here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#25383C"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bRemove"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which is the 137 line of profileCreation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currentUser.put("Minimum_Age", seekBarMinimum);
currentUser.put("Maximum_Age", seekBarMaximum);
currentUser.put("Maximum_Distance_Age", seekBarDistance);
```

Here instead of setting the seekbar value you are setting the seekbar itself.

use the following:

```
currentUser.put("Minimum_Age", seekBarMinimum.getProgress());
currentUser.put("Maximum_Age", seekBarMaximum.getProgress());
currentUser.put("Maximum_Distance_Age", seekBarDistance.getProgress());
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response and clarification. Upon applying those changes, I have received the following popup message error: "Object not found for update".

Comment: You mean it is entering `else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }` block?

Comment: Yes it is entering the else statement which I find it odd because when seekbar is not refered other information like age, gender, headline, name..etc are being recorded at parse, so i just find it odd that only the seekbars are not processing. Essentially the user records information such as minimum age, maximum age, and search distance using seekbar, and where its value is updated in respective textfield, but for some reason i can't record that information. I appreciate your support thus far, and if you could assist me further, that would be truly helpful

Comment: @user3827788 I think it might be because of the type. `getProgress()` returns `int` try using `String.valueOf(seekBarMaximum.getProgress())`. This is just an assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I recieve the following error upon revising the code: "invalid type for key
Maximum_Age, expected number but got a string" But why couldn't i just record the number, for instance age is a number and that gets recorded, or maybe I am just confused

Comment: Then it is expecting int only. Please remove `String.ValueOf()`. Sorry about that! May be you can share your entire code to check. I cannot see anyother way to figure this out. Since my answer solved your original question please accept it.

Comment: As suggested, I have removed String.ValueOf(), however this just prompts me back to the following error  of "Object not found for update". I have updated my entire code under the update section of my intial post, and it would be helpful if you could kindly take a look at it. Most certainly you have answered my initial question well, and I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59301/discussion-between-rani-and-user3827788).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was adding the dynamic radio group and buttons,
finally I just added the following the code in the manifesto file for the particular activity:

```
<activity android:name="Activity_" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```